# Run function then follow link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I can't seem to find an example of what I'm trying to do here but I'm sure it's possible.

Consider the following:

```
<div id="main_nav">
    <a href="/url/">LINK</a>
    <a href="/url/">LINK</a>
    <a href="/url/">LINK</a>
    <a href="/url/">LINK</a>
</div>
```

How can I run a function when a `link` within `#main_nav` is clicked before then following the `link`?

The below doesn't work as the link is followed before the function is run.

```
$('#main_nav a').click(function() {
    // Some Function
});
```

**EDIT**

I'm actually trying to clear a cookie with the JQuery cookie plugin when the links are clicked. I'm not sure if this is relevant or not.

The Clear cookie code is:

```
$.cookie('TMMenu', null);
```

TMMenu is the correct name and the plugin is loaded.

**EDIT**

Sorry everyone. The problem was actually with the [JQuery Cookie plugin documentation](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

```
$.cookie('TMMenu', null);
```

as described in the readme doesn't seem to work. This does:

```
$.cookie('TMMenu', null, { path: '/', expires: -5 });
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code.  The body of `click` will run and then the link will be followed.  What problem are you seeing?

Comment: Sounds like you need a callback of some sort.

Comment: Are you trying to perform an asynchronous behavior before the link is navigated to, such as an animation, or AJAX request?

Comment: I'm actually trying to clear a cookie with "$.cookie('TMMenu', null);" when the link is clicked but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Update**: Re your edit: I can't see any reason that wouldn't work other than #1 below.

I can think of two answers to this question:

1. You're running your jQuery code before the `#main_nav a` element exists, and no event handler is hooked up. Put your script at the bottom of the HTML file, just before the closing `</body>` tag, or use the [`ready` callback](http://api.jquery.com/ready).
2. You're doing something asynchronous in your handler, and not seeing it happen. That's because as soon as the event handler returns, the link gets followed — even if your handler initiates some asynchronous action.

Here's how to fix the second one (both, if you put this at the end or inside a `ready` handler):

```
$('#main_nav a').click(function(event) {
    // Remember the link href
    var href = this.href;

    // Don't follow the link
    event.preventDefault();

    // Do the async thing
    startSomeAsyncThing(function() {
        // This is the completion callback for the asynchronous thing;
        // go to the link
        window.location = href;
    });
});
```

([Live copy](http://jsbin.com/itejim) | [source](http://jsbin.com/itejim/edit#html))

Comment: I'll mark you as correct for providing an interesting example. The problem was actually with the code I was using to delete a cookie. Many thanks

Comment: @3rror404: Glad you found it useful! Much as I appreciate the rep, it would be better if you posted your own answer saying what it was and then (after 48 hours) accepted it. I'll take an upvote if you haven't already, though. ;-) (Or you could flag your question, asking a moderator to remove it, since it's probably not useful for others...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Will this solution work for links that have been ctrl-clicked or right-clicked and opened in a new tab?

Comment: @pdoherty926: No. Control-click, with the code above, will just be treated as a regular click (because we aren't checking the state of the control key). We could detect the control-click, but we can't open a new tab in the async callback (because the browser's popup-blocker will prevent it, because it's not in *direct* response to a user event). And there's nothing we can do about right-click "Open in new tab."

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you do it. If you call `event.preventDefault` in your click handler callback it will prevent the default action. Then to follow the link via Javascript just use `window.open(url)` or `window.location = url`.

### Plain Javascript example

```
document.querySelector('#main_nav a').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  // Do something before following the link 

  // Get url from the target element (<a>) href attribute
  var url = event.target.href;

  // Open the url in the current window. Set to "_blank" instead of "_self" to open in a new window.
  window.open(url, '_self');

  // Prevent default action (e.g. following the link)
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

### jQuery Example

```
$('#main_nav a').click(function (event) {
  // Do something before following the link 

  // Get url from the <a> href attribute
  var url = $(this).attr('href');

  // Open the url in the current window. Set to "_blank" instead of "_self" to open in a new window.
  window.open(url, "_self");

  // Prevent default action (e.g. following the link)
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

See MDN for more information on the differences between `window.open` and `window.location`.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location