# Cancel confirm button issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on the link below they are getting the confirm prompt, but the cancel button still sends them to the URL. I'm checking if they have filled in any text fields to warn them about data loss.

Edit: I have to use onclick

```
<a class="owl-prev button disabled" href="blabla.com" onclick="checking()"> back</a>


jQuery(window).load(function(){
checking = function() {

    var empty = 0;
   jQuery('.tmcp-textfield').each(function(){
       if (this.value != "") {
           empty++;
       } 
    })
   if(empty > 1)
   {
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
   }

}});
```

Comment: did you forget to return something? *hint: the answer is yes*

Comment: Looks like you have posted not all code. Where is `.tmcp-textfield`?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide it's a standard textbox, the counter works it's the confirm that's broken

Comment: `checking` is properly returning the result of the confirm, but then you did nothing with said result in the event handler.

Comment: Where is the function definition?

Comment: Function definitions don't need to be put inside `$(window).load()`. Also, this use of `.load()` is deprecated. Either use `$(document).ready()` or use `$(window).on("load", ...)`

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the hint, in case you can't tell from the code above im super new and trying to make a WP theme do something that is using old jQuery. Does the confirm return a bool? What do i do with it?

Comment: @loveforfire33 jafarbtech's answer fixes the problem i was pointing out. but... you don't really need the if conditional included in that answer. you could simply return checking().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the return of onclick function to return false if the validation is set to false abd change the checking as `empty > 0`

**Demo:**

```js
checking = function() {
  var empty = 0;
  jQuery('.tmcp-textfield').each(function() {
    if (this.value != "") {
      empty++;
    }
  })
  if (empty > 0) {
    return confirm('If you go back, all typed data will be lost. Do you still want to go back?');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="tmcp-textfield" placeholder="Name" /><br/>
<input class="tmcp-textfield" placeholder="City" /><br/><br/>
<a class="owl-prev button disabled" href="https://blabla.com" onclick="return checking();"> back</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to prevent the default event, and then manuallly redirect if `(empty > 1)`.

Try `event.preventDefault()`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945582/5775828 for a further explanation

Answer (score -2):

I would try and remove the anchor tag and use something else to prevent the default behaviour. try button tag ?