# Event after link followed

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, css-position, relative-url

Is there a JavaScript event that is triggered after a relative link within the page has been followed?
I.e. a link of the form

```html
<a href="#id">text</a>
```

Background: I'm working under the constraints of a silly layout that has a navigation bar with CSS properties

```css
position: fixed;
top: 0;
height: 55px;
```

When a relative link is followed, the link target is at the top of the viewport, but under the navigation bar and therefore invisible. My idea is to scroll up by 65px after the link has been followed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945371/run-function-then-follow-link